# From a large text file to a sparse matrix with Python

Tags: python, text, sparse-matrix

I am trying to find an efficient way to read a very large text file (about 2,000,000 lines). About 90% of these lines (the last 90% actually) have a three-column format and are used for storing a sparse matrix.

Here is what I did. First of all, I deal with the first 10% of the file:

```
i=1
cpt=0
skip=0
finnum=0
indice=1 
vec=[]
mat=[]
for line in fileinput.input("MY_TEXT_FILE.TXT"):
if i==1:
    # skipping the first line
    skip = 1
if (finnum == 0)and(skip==0):
    # special reading operation for the first 10% (approximately)
    tline=shlex.split(line)
    ind_loc=0
    while ind_loc<len(tline):
    if (int(tline[ind_loc])!=0):
            vec.append(int(tline[ind_loc]))
        ind_loc=ind_loc+1   
if (finnum == 1)and(skip==0):
    print('finnum = 1')
    h=input()    
        break       
    if (' 0' in line):
    finnum = 1
if skip == 0:
    i=i+1
else:
    skip=0
    i=i+1
cpt=cpt+1
```

Then I extract the remaining 90% into a list:

```
matrix=[]
with open('MY_TEXT_FILE.TXT') as f:
for i in range(cpt):
    f.next()
for line in f:
    matrix.append(line)
```

This allows for a very fast read through of the text file with low memory consumption. The drawback is that **matrix** is a list of strings, each string being something like:

```
>>> matrix[23]
'           5          11  8.320234929063493E-008\n'
```

I have tried to use an iterative procedure over the lines of **matrix** combined with the **shlex.split** command to go from a list of strings to an array but this is extremely time consuming.

Would you be aware of fast strategies to go from a list of strings to an array ?

What I would like to know is if there is something faster than this procedure :

```
A=[0]*len(matrix)
B=[0]*len(matrix)
C=[0]*len(matrix)
for i in range(len(matrix)):
     line = shlex.split(matrix[i])
     A[i]=float(line[0])
     B[i]=float(line[1])
     C[i]=float(line[2])
```

Alain

Comment: "to go from a list of strings to an array" What do you acutally want to do? Do you want to hold the matrix (= list of list) in memory?

Comment: I want to be able to access each numerical value of my list and to obtain the associated (nx3) matrix.

Comment: Can you somehow modify the format of the file? Because it sounds like something that HDF5 fits perfectly.

Comment: I don't exactly have access to the format of the file, it is given by an external routine that I do not control unfortunately...

Comment: Can you time how long it takes to read a million of these lines? Just to understand a bit more

Comment: It takes less than 3 seconds to get my list of strings **matrix** and about 95 seconds to read 1,400,000 lines and obtain the arrays A, B and C. It advantageously consume very few RAM memory. However, if I compare it with the **importdata** function in Matlab, a similar operation would take roughly 5 seconds...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look, I came up with this mixed solution that seems to work way faster. I created a 1 million sample random data like the one you mentioned above and timed your code. It took 77 seconds in my Mac computer which is a super fast computer by the way.
Using numpy to split the string instead of shlex ended up in a 5 seconds processing process.

```
A=[0]*len(matrix)
B=[0]*len(matrix)
C=[0]*len(matrix)
for i in range(len(matrix)):
    full_array = np.fromstring(matrix[i], dtype=float, sep=" ")
    A[i]=full_array[0]
    B[i]=full_array[1]
    C[i]=full_array[2]
```

I made a couple of tests and it seems to work well and it's 14 times faster.
I hope it helps.

Comment: Great ! Way faster indeed, seems to work beautifully. Thanks !

Comment: I guessed the problem could have been shlex due to the objective of this library, it's really good but not for this goal.

Answer (score 2):

When you are working with this large amount of numerical data, you should really be working with [Numpy](http://www.numpy.org/), not with pure python. This is typically more than a factor 10 faster and gives you access to Matlab style complicated calculations. I don't have time now to convert your code (and it would be easiest to have a sample file), but for sure reading the second part of your file can be done fast and efficiently using [numpy.loadtxt](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html). The whole second part of your code for skipping the first part and converting to float can probably be done with something like this:

```
A, B, C = np.loadtxt('MY_TEXT_FILE.TXT', skiprows = cpt, unpack = True)
```

You might want to play with the data format (by adding `dtype = (int, int, float)` or so, don't know exactly how to do this), since I guess the first two columns are integers.

Also note that numpy has a [sparse matrix](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/sparse.html) datatype available.

Comment: Thanks for this proposition. However, this implies a significant consumption of RAM memory (similar to the **importdata** function in Matlab). And I am trying to avoid this. It is faster though.

Comment: Is the memory consuming a big issue for you? Because I cannot think on anything faster than this

Comment: Memory consumption is actually the reason why I try to use Python for this reading operation. The **importdata** command in Matlab may sometimes require too much RAM. The current solution is not extremely slow but I wanted to make sure there is no obvious improvement that I was missing. Thanks !

Comment: I assume that under the hood, loadtxt reads only one line of text at a time and then converts it directly to float, so you only need space for the A, B and C arrays. Arrays of a few million items shouldn't be an issue on any modern computer. In case the files would be much bigger, you should consider reading the file in blocks of say 100.000 lines at a time. Maybe you need a variant like numpy.fromfile or numpy.genfromtxt, since loadtxt does not seem to handle file pointers and does not have an option to limit the amount of data you read. But most probably you don't need this.